# Django double import during tests

Tags: python, django, django-models, runtime-error, python-import

whenever I run Django tests, I fall into a double import trap with my models.

Every time I get

```
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'userdevice' models in application 'cart': <class 'cart.models.devices.UserDevice'> and <class 'fridge.libs.cart.models.devices.UserDevice'>
```

Minimal failing example is at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/m802q544cet5dui/AACRGOMQXWqxUzi92WfqfvYea?dl=0

My folder structure is

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── milk
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── tests
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── test_commands.py
├── __init__.py
├── libs
│   ├── cart
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── models
│   │       ├── devices.py
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── Makefile
├── manage.py
└── settings
    ├── __init__.py
    └── settings.py
```

I have `apps` and `libs` folders in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

My `models/__init__.py` file contains

```
from .devices import *
```

From `test_commands.py` I include model with

```
from cart.models import UserDevice
```

I read multiple questions here at SO and some articles on web. I was also debugging this for a few hours, so I know the problem is that my model is imported twice. Once during the Django project initialization as `cart.models.devices.UserDevice` and once by the `unittest` library as `fridge.libs.cart.models.devices.UserDevice` but I simply do not know how to fix this situation.

This is also causing more problems in files, which can be initialized only once during the app run, but I guess that the solution will be same as to this one.

I am using Django 1.10.8 as this is a legacy project but I experience the same on Django 2.0.7.

Python version is 3.5. OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks for any advice or hint. Nothing I found so far did not help.

**Edit**

So I experimented a bit and the problem persist even when no import are made in tests and even if there are no tests at all. Just running the tests will make the double import and `RuntimeError` happen

No-tests version: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qqzg842rihbh5im/AADzay8up3d_rFKqy2OAsx1za?dl=0

New folder structure

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── libs
│   ├── cart
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── models
│   │       ├── devices.py
│   │       └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── Makefile
├── manage.py
└── settings
    ├── __init__.py
    └── settings.py
```

**Edit:**

For the future's sake - content of `libs/cart/models/devices.py` is just simple Django model class

```
from django.db import models


class UserDevice(models.Model):

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'cart'
```

Comment: I ran your tests for your sample project and it worked.

Comment: @aliva Did you run them through `Makefile`/`manage.py` file with Python 3.5? Well, something must be different if it's working for you :(

Comment: you are right I had this issue on python3

Comment: Its weird... you are initing your imports globaly? you should import things only when you need to use it... besides settings ofc, so when you run unittest, he will important necessary things at your testesuite and run, after this testsuite finishes he will close everything

Comment: @DiegoVinícius Well I want to use the `UserDevice` model in my test and it is the only place I import it. But it is still imported twice with different paths

Comment: You probabily facing circular importation, check if any function that you using isnt importing UserDevice or your testecase that already import UserDevice

Comment: Cant see your app cart in ur dropbox

Comment: nvm, i placed it in libs, found now

Comment: im not sure, but this could be problem at your pyc files too... maybe in somepoint you placed that import in other file and removed it... but the pyc didnt update it

Comment: @DiegoVinícius I tried deleting all `.pyc` files and `pycache` folders but the problem still persists. I edited the original question - the problem appears even when no tests are present in project and thus no manual imports of model.

Comment: Try to change of cart.models import * to cart.models import UserDevice

Comment: @DiegoVinícius Still the same. Even when I do not import the model at all, it is double imported on test run

Comment: You are able to run runserver? try make some random view to display hello word at your cart app and tell me if it work... i just want one sanity check if your cart is properly imported

Comment: from cart.models import UserDevice but your cart app is inside libs... so you should put a path to libs... and your models isnt models it its devices.py... so try libs.cart.models.devices import UserDevice (You follow one path way out of django structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow "solved" the problem by deleting `libs/__init__.py` file. I am not sure why it was present in the project in the first place.